# How can I create rows and columns for buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making my own version of minesweeper and i need to display my buttons in a 8x8 grid like in minesweeper.

i have already tried using 'button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)' but this displays the buttons as 1 row

for i in range(64):

```
    button = tk.Button(frame,
                        text="0",
                        command=randomnum)
    button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

I thought this would display up to the edges of the window but it goes of the window.

Comment: The `pack` geometry isn't going to work for this unless you use a bunch of frames.  Check the `tkinter` docs for info on the `grid` geometry.
https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html

  Here's a couple little tutorials to get you started.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pack manager can't handle something like this.  You can do it by making a bunch of frames and packing each column or row individually, but the easiest way is to step away from tkinter's pack manager and start using the grid manager for this.  Here is some sample code for a gui that doesn't do anything but shows you a grid:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

class maingui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("sample gui")

        self.button=Button(text="1")
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.button=Button(text="2")
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.button=Button(text="3")
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.button=Button(text="4")
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.button=Button(text="5")
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.button=Button(text="6")
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.button=Button(text="7")
        self.button.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.button=Button(text="8")
        self.button.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.button=Button(text="9")
        self.button.grid(row=3, column=3)

root = Tk()
gui = maingui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Sample Grid Gui]

If you want the buttons added as a loop, you can do something like:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

class maingui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("sample gui")

        a=1
        b=1
        for i in range(1, 65):
            self.button=Button(text=i)
            self.button.grid(row=a, column=b)
            b=b+1
            if b==9:
                b=1
                a=a+1

root = Tk()
gui = maingui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this but i am struggling on how to implement it into my code

Comment: I just included the complete code for the 64 button grid, created in a for loop.  Obviously there are no functions or anything attached to the buttons and I just named them their number, but this code will give you an 8x8 grid.

Comment: Is everything indented properly?  You will get that error if your buttons aren't included as part of `__init__`.  Make sure it's indented exactly like it is above.  I just tested it again.  It works.

Comment: Awesome.  If this answer fixed your problem, please select it as "accepted" if it isn't too much trouble.  In general, when you ask questions in the future, it's general good practice to accept the one you end up using, both to assist future question viewers and to provide a reputation boost for the answerer.